# DataGrid style not binding. A style intended for type 'DataGridRow' cannot be applied to type 'DataGridRow'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I have a DataGrid that I initialized like so:

```
<Custom:DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,100,0,45" Width="420" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowBackground="Transparent" RowHeaderWidth="0"
                                     Background="#FFEFEFEF" Foreground="{DynamicResource LabelForeground}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource StyleA}"
                                     ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyleA}"
                                     CellStyle="{DynamicResource CellStyleA}" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"  SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                      CanUserSortColumns="True">
        <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding GrdDenomination,Source={StaticResource LiteralDictionary }}" Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DenominationTemplate}" SortMemberPath="Denomination"/>
        </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
    </Custom:DataGrid>
```

and my Style is initialized as such:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleA" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseDown1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    .....
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "A style intended for type 'DataGridRow' cannot be applied to type 'DataGridRow'."

This makes no sense to me and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your error should probably be read as: "A style intended for type 'System.Window.Controls.DataGridRow' cannot be applied to type 'My.Controls.Custom.DataGridRow'." Try `<Style x:Key="StyleA" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridRow}">`.

Comment: looks like you're using a custom control `DataGrid` which may even have its own `DataGridRow` type. You should try exploring about that actual type (its full name), so that you can reference it inside the `Style` (instead of `TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"`, it should be something like `TargetType="{x:Type someNamespace:DataGridRow}"`)

Comment: @Athari I tried your solution, and the exception is gone, but now it's not binding properly. So, custom is the name of the WPFToolkit namespace accessor.

xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"